# How to show the new array values

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have array like `arraypartno`, it contains `80` values, have to show the`20-20 values` in `tableview cell` and `next 20 values` on `click` of next button like paging.
But when i click on next button it add on the values  and increase the cell like `40`,then `60` values so on. But i want `20 values` first then next `20 values` on `tableview` cell,like paging ....

Please guide me to solve this issue. Thanks You

Heres the code for Table view cell:-

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *lblplate1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 30)];

lblplate1.text = [arraypartno  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

lblplate1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
lblplate1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:143.0/255.0 blue:213.0/255.0 alpha:1];
lblplate1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
lblplate1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblplate1];
[lblplate1 release];
lblplate1 = nil;

return cell;
```

}

lowvalue initialize from 0 ,it increase when click on next button

```
 -(void)next:(id)sender
 {
  lowvalue= lowvalue+20;

  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://demo.com/New/web_serv/wspartsearch.php?search=%@&start=%d&count=20",searchText,lowvalue];

}
```

It decrease when click on previous button

```
-(void)previous:(id)sender
{
lowvalue= lowvalue-20;

 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://demo.com/New/web_serv/wspartsearch.php?search=%@&start=%d&count=20",searchText,lowvalue];

}
```

I want only 20 values at a time.

Comment: Please add your code @Verma

Comment: I edit the question now chk @Rushi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the objects which are already in `NSArray` before adding next 20 objects in it.

try:

```
[myArray removeAllObjects];
```

Then add next 20 objects in your array.

Then reload your tableview.

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

Initalize `totalShowCount = 20;` `(totalShowCount < [arraypartno count])`

1) In `numberOfRowsInSection` datasource method `return totalShowCount-1;`

2) In next button action, update `totalShowCount`with next 20 values, like `totalShowCount+=20`;

3) `[tableview reloadData];`

You may need some condition on next button `if(totalShowCount<[arraypartno count])` then only perform 2nd and 3rd step.

Answer (score 1):

**By Default numberOfItemsToDisplay = 20;**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        if (numberOfItemsToDisplay >= [self.aryAlerts count])
        {
            numberOfItemsToDisplay = [self.aryAlerts count];
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCustomCell";
            YourCustomCell *objYourCustomCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (objYourCustomCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
                {
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[YourCustomCell class]])
                    {
                        objYourCustomCell = (AlertsCustomCell *) currentObject;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            objYourCustomCell.lbl.text = [[self.aryAlerts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"vName"];
            return objYourCustomCell;
        }
        else
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {

                cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:[self loadMoreViewForTable:self.view]];
            }
            return cell;
        }
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.tblAlertsList deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            numberOfItemsToDisplay =  [self loadMore:numberOfItemsToDisplay arrayTemp:self.aryAlerts tblView:self.tblAlertsList];
            [self.tblAlertsList endUpdates];
        }else
        {
           // action if it is not LoadMore
        }
    }

    + (NSInteger)loadMore : (NSInteger)numberOfItemsToDisplay arrayTemp:(NSMutableArray*)aryItems tblView:(UITableView*)tblList
    {
        int count =0;
        NSUInteger i, totalNumberOfItems = [aryItems count];
        NSUInteger newNumberOfItemsToDisplay = MIN(totalNumberOfItems, numberOfItemsToDisplay + kNumberOfItemsToAdd);
        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (i=numberOfItemsToDisplay; i<newNumberOfItemsToDisplay; i++)
        {
            count++;
            [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        }
        numberOfItemsToDisplay = newNumberOfItemsToDisplay;
        [tblList beginUpdates];
        [tblList insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        if (numberOfItemsToDisplay == totalNumberOfItems) {
            [tblList deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
        NSIndexPath *scrollPointIndexPath;
        if (newNumberOfItemsToDisplay < totalNumberOfItems)
        {
            scrollPointIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfItemsToDisplay-kNumberOfItemsToAdd inSection:0];
        }
        else
        {
            scrollPointIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i-count inSection:0];
        }
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 100000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [tblList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollPointIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone  animated:YES];
        });
        return numberOfItemsToDisplay;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have predefined initialized array of 80 objects make a 2nd `NSMutableArray` for data source i name it `dataElements` that will be present data in `tableView`.Now at every `ViewDidLoad` (or if you are in same view then make this update in your `nextMethod`) make a loop and copy 20 values at `dataElements` from your "`arraypartno`"
e.g
1.Make `int counter=0;`
2.make `NsMutableArray`.I named it `dataElements`

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender{

            if(counter < 20){
                for(int i=0 ; i<20 ;i++ ){
                    [dataElements addObject:[arraypartno objectAtIndex:i]];
                    counter++;
                }
            }else if(counter<40){
                for(int i=20 ; i<40 ;i++ ){
                    [dataElements replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[arraypartno objectAtIndex:i]];
                    counter++;
                }
            }else if(counter<60){
                for(int i=40 ; i<60 ;i++ ){
                    [dataElements replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[arraypartno objectAtIndex:i]];
                    counter++;
                }
            }else if(counter<80){
                for(int i=60 ; i<80 ;i++ ){
                    [dataElements replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[arraypartno objectAtIndex:i]];
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [dataElements count];



    //OR
    // return 20;
    }
```

If you still  have confusion please ask it.